# RegEx to match first number except 0, but including numbers like 10, 50 and similar

Tags: regex

I need regex that matches the first number except "0", but including 10, 20, 30, 40 etc.
I tried using the below but this one excludes numbers like 10, 50 and similar.

`\d+[^0](?=;)`

**Examples:**

| value | regex should match |
| --- | --- |
| 0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;51;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;51;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0 | 51 |
| 0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;50;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;50;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0 | 50 |
| 0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;100;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;123;0;0;0;0;0;0;0 | 100 |

Comment: Try it like this `\b0*[1-9]\d*\b`

Comment: Do you mean to say you want to match from 1 to 100 only? There is `123` in the third line, but you do not want to extract it, do you? Also, what programming language are you using?

Comment: why is 51 matched, but not 123? if only `0` is allowed after non `0` try: `(?<=^|;)[1-9]0*(?=;)`. If only the number must not start with 0 then try: `(?<=^|;)[1-9][0-9]*(?=;)`. If you only want the first value returned unset the regex `g` option.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I'd like to find the FIRST number which is not 0

Comment: The first number which is not zero `^.*?\b(0*[1-9]\d*)\b` https://regex101.com/r/LHB6gm/1 or if pcre is available `^.*?\b\K0*[1-9]\d*\b`  https://regex101.com/r/L17gYc/1

Comment: or [1-9]\d+(?<=)

Comment: Then it is not a programming question, you need to ask on the tool forum for help. However, it seems all you need is to use the `Preg Match` box for this, and the top comment solution should work well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the regex pattern:

```
\b(?!0\b)\d+\b
```

This says to match:

- `\b` a word boundary (either start/end of string or semicolon separator)
- `(?!0\b)` assert that what follows is NOT 0 followed by word boundary
- `\d+` but then match any other integer number
- `\b` word boundary

Here is a working regex [demo](https://regex101.com/r/GkVBuj/1).

Comment: This would work, except that it matches all numbers, but not just the first one. How can I limit it to the first number?

Comment: You need to reveal the tool or language you are using.

Comment: It's for a rule box in Productsup.

Answer (score 1):

As you mention in the previous comments that this is for Productsup, [this page](https://help.productsup.com/en/29493-38635-transform-data-with-regular-expressions-and-split-strings.html#UUID-70141e7b-a122-220c-c1c4-a7d36decda6d_section-idm4550938432441633045222399102)  mentions "Preg Match" which would match the first occurrence if that is the same as the [php equivalent](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php).

You can match optional zeroes and then match a digit 1-9 followed by optional digits:

```
\b0*[1-9]\d*\b
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/MUFQYu/1)

---

If you want to validate the format of the string, you could assert that the string only consists of digits and semicolons:

```
^(?=[\d;]+$).*?\K0*[1-9]\d*
```

The pattern matches:

- `^` Start of string
- `(?=[\d;]+$)` Positive lookahead, assert only digits and semicolons until the end of the string
- `.*?` Match any character, as few as possible
- `\K` Forget what is matched so far
- `0*[1-9]\d*` Match optional zeroes, a single digit 1-9 and optional digits

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Ag8eRI/1)